# How to interrupt the input stream which bind to istream_iterator

Tags: c++

```
istream_iterator<string> input(cin), eos;
vector<string> text;

copy(input, eos, back_inserter(text));
```

how to  interrupt the **input(cin)** on Ubuntu Linux and Windows?

Comment: Have you tried `CTRL-Z` on Windows and `CTRL-D` on Linux? These are the end-of-file keys used in respective system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu Linux:
   Ctrl + d(D)
On Windows:
   Ctrl + z(Z)